# VSCode format code doesn't work with typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode 1.11 with typescript 2.2.2.

I am currently programming with Angular 2 and I noticed that I'm not able to have the 'format code' command work anymore with Typescript files. And it doesn't work in this Angular project only. By the way I have Windows.

The 'format code' was perfectly working before.

---

What I tried:

- I created a new typescript file in another empty folder and the 'format code' works fine but not in my Angular project.
- I noticed that when I remove the `node_modules` folder, the 'format code' works again.
- So maybe there is something wrong in the `node_modules` folder, so I remove this folder, I deleted the `npm-cache` folder in `AppData` and I launch `npm install`. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have `"typescript.tsdk"` set in your workspace? Also, what extensions do you have installed?

Comment: @MattBierner Yes I tried to set in my workspace settings `"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules\\typescript\\lib"` or `"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"` or `"typescript.tsdk": "C:/[path to my Angular project]/node_modules/typescript/lib"` or "typescript.tsdk": "C:\\[path to my Angular project]\\node_modules\\typescript\\lib" and it's not working. I have `Angular 2+ Snippets` as extension. I tried to remove it it doesn't change anything. Without extension, format code works in another folder but not in my Angular project.

Comment: Try setting `"typescript.tsserver.trace": "verbose"` and restarting VSCode. Then reproduce the issue and open the TypeScript section of the output window. This may provide more information on what is going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved.
Today a new update of VSCode was released (1.12). I installed it and now I can finally use the 'format code' shortcut.